# Web Sites: Disneyland vs Disney World in the United States

Tags: tickets, terminology, scams, disney

I was looking for Disney tickets and I found these 2 sites ([Disneyland](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/tickets/?numDays=3) and [Disneyworld](https://disneyworld.disney.go.com/tickets/) ) that look exactly like each other.

However, one of them is way cheaper than the other. Which one can I trust?

Comment: Disneyland and Disneyworld are two entirely different places, one in California and one in Florida. Which one do you want tickets for? Both those are official Disney web sites, which is why they look similar.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea...I want go to Orlando, which one is it?

Comment: I didn't know there were 2 Disneys! I almost bought the cheapest one...probably there are lots of people who end up doing that. If someone could add an answer for future reference of those ignorant folks like me...

Comment: There are more than two - there are Disney parks in Paris, Tokyo, Hong Kong, Shanghai, and probably others.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about the foreigners ones, what I didn't know was that EUA had two.

Comment: (EUA = États-Unis d'Amérique = USA)

Comment: @MSalters Actually , (EUA = Estados Unidos da América). I completely forgot that we say USA in english...=P Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @carla: I guessed from "foreign ones" that you also had a domestic Disney park, i.e. EuroDisney. AFAIK there's no Disney park in Spanish-speaking countries.

Comment: @MSalters Neither in Portuguese-speaking countries, that is my case . ;)

Comment: @Dorothy - you wrote "Disney World" twice in your comment, but the Cali one is Disneyland.

Comment: @GregHewgill that is the compete list (at least for now).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Those are two different official Disney sites and are for purchasing tickets for two very different parks:

- Disneyland is in Anaheim, California and opened in 1955.
- Walt Disney World is in Orlando, Florida and opened in 1971.

Answer (score 34):

Those are both official Disney sites, but the tickets are for two different Disney Resorts, **Disneyland**, which is located in Anaheim, California, and **Disney World**, which is located in Orlando, Florida.

There are many options for tickets in both complexes, but typically tickets either allow access to one park per day (the cheaper option), or are "park-hopper" tickets that allow switching between parks within a day. Obviously for one day tickets the former is equivalent to buying a ticket to a single park.

#### Disney World

Is by far the larger resort, and includes the Magic Kingdom Park, the Epcot centre, Hollywood Studios, the Animal Kingdom Park and the Water Park.

#### Disneyland

Includes Disneyland Park and Disney California Adventure Park. It most closely resembles the Magic Kingdom part of Disney World though there are several differences.

Comment: Disneyworld ... includes the Magic Kingdom Park, the Epcot centre, Hollywood Studios, the Animal Kingdom Park and the Water Park." - since the question is about tickets, it's important to know that they're only co-located. Tickets are separate, park entrances are separate.

Comment: Same for Disneyland Park and Disney California Adventure Park. They're on the same site but they are separate attractions that require separate tickets.

Comment: Or you can get one ticket that works for both. There's a couple different ticket options you have to research and choose the best one for what you plan to do.

Comment: @MSalters there are park-hopper tickets (adds a little bit to the ticket price) that allow visitors to attend multiple parks in the same day. Parking fees are also by _day_ not by _park_. With a park-hopper option on a ticket, a visitor could pay for parking at Magic Kingdom, then go to Hollywood Studios using the same admission ticket and not pay a dime extra to park or get in.

Comment: It's not been called Epcot Centre for over 20 years, and there are two water parks (Blizzard Beach & Typhoon Lagoon), along with Disney Springs, ESPN, four golf courses, and two themed miniature golf complexes, each with two courses. The place is friggin' huge.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the clarifications and additional info. I've updated my post.
@Jocie well that makes sense, as the last time I was there was just over 20 years ago, as a 12 year-old!

Answer (score 8):

From what I saw the prices are not all that different.  At Orlando $97, CA $85.  Keep in mind that Orlando has four different (main) parks:  Animal Kingdom, Hollywood Studios, Magic Kingdom, and Epcot.  There are also water parks on site that also have separate entrance fees.  Entrance into each varies in prices so the $97 is just an estimate.  Passes that allow someone to "park hop" are more expensive than passes to that park for the day.

A vacation to the Orlando theme parks is anything but cheap.  There are ways to save money but it is still pretty expensive.

Both sites are very trustworthy in that they are Disney owned and operated.  If you call them they will make a nice package for you to enjoy your stay.  This would include meal plans, stays on property, and special tours.

For one of my wife's birthdays we did a special guided tour of Animal Kingdom that she still talks about to this day.  It was about 4 years ago.  We've also SCUBA dove the Epcot aquarium, but you have to be a certified diver to do so.  It was a bit of a high price, $170 each, but it was about half the price of doing the same at the Atlanta aquarium.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact question and after a little bit of searching I did find a [resource online](https://www.parksavers.com/disneyland-vs-disney-world/) that helps explain the difference. Disneyland Resort is much smaller than Walt Disney World Resort it. Disneyland is made up of 2 parks and a shopping district. You can walk to all 3 places in minutes.

Walt Disney World Resort is made up of 4 parks, 2 water parks and a shopping district. You can to drive between all 6 of these things (except Hollywood Studios and Epcot).

Most people spend 3 days at Disneyland vs. 5 days at Walt Disney World.

Disneyland is also cheaper than a Walt Disney World trip usually because of food, ticket and hotel prices.